# How can I keep something, anything, compiling forever?

Tags: compiling

How can I keep something always compiling on a spare machine?

As it's just for looks, the more complex looking the better. I don't care what it is, just so long as it doesn't require input on my part, and it repeats forever.

I'll be using some flavor of Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I Wish I could mark more than one as correct, since they'll all work. I went with hollywood, since it's so easy to implement, and I can get back to my actual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for something looking busy? Don't care about any productive output?

Check out `hollywood`. There is a link [here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Imitate-Fake-Hollywood-Terminal-Hacking-Melodrama-with-this-Amazing-App-for-Ubuntu-467788.shtml) talking about it, and spotting it in the wild.

Comment: This is even better than what I'd imagined! The less computer literate people will think it's real, and the more computer literate people can just look at my actual screen and see that I'm working. Great!

Comment: Beware -- for a computer literate person, it is pretty obvious that's a fake. You will need to do better than that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want it for looks, [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30322/make-it-look-like-im-working) question and its answers might be useful. I wasn't super happy with the accepted answer when I tried it out, but I did like the [compilation emulator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/30340) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eeh.. ok. Something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    gcc -v <your code>.c -o <your binary>
done
```

**Why** you would like to do this however, is above my paygrade!

*Warning: Might cause epileptic seizures!*

Comment: Because this? https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: @pepper_chico Haha!

Comment: That xkcd comic did inspire the question, but not for the reasons you might think. I'm always super busy at work, but plenty of the people I support don't quite understand that sometimes I need to sit in front of my own computer to get something done. I just want something that helps them understand that I'm busy, and looks cool in the process. What better than compiling code?!

Comment: Fair enough. If you run that script, they will probably leave you alone!